# How to efficiently delete all indices with certain value in one list out of both lists?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays from which I am trying to delete all indices which have the value -1 in the second array.

Example:

```
goldLabels = np.array([12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5])
predictions = np.array([12, 3, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1])
```

Expected result:

```
>>> print(goldLabels)
[12, 2, 0, 0]  
>>> print(predictions) 
[12, 3, 0, 2]
```

This is my code so far:

```
idcs = []
for idx, label in enumerate(goldLabels):
    if label == -1: 
        idcs.append(idx)
goldLabels = np.delete(goldLabels, idcs)
predictions = np.delete(predictions, idcs)
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Where's array1 and 2 used in the code?

Comment: Because you're using parallel arrays I think this is a good solution. Otherwise something like https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter would be good

Comment: For array inputs, use a mask - `mask = goldLabels!=-1; predictions[mask],goldLabels[mask]`.

Comment: @Divakar It was just an example. Maybe I should have used the actual names. I clarified it in the question.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks man. Just tested it. Was quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's capabilities to directly extract those numbers using a mask:

```
goldLabels = np.array([12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5])
predictions = np.array([12, 3, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1])

mask = predictions!=-1 
predictions = predictions[mask]
goldLabels = goldLabels[mask]

print(goldLabels)
print(predictions)
```

Output:

```
[12  2  0  0]
[12  3  0  2]
```